# Passing variable into included twig template that has variable in template name

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to pass variables into an included twig template, where the template name is a variable in itself?

```
{% include('MyMainBundle:MyEntity:' ~ entity.templateName) %}
```

works, but when I try to also pass a variable into this template, twig throws a syntax error.

```
{% include('MyMainBundle:MyEntity:' ~ entity.templateName, {'name' : myName} ) %}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I see what I was doing wrong. I had combined two different versions of include, one using {{ and the other using {% due to the symfony and twig docs showing different ways of including templates.  This was as simple as removing the parenthesis from my initial code and inserting a with prior to defining the argument.

You can include a template like this per http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates

```
{{ include('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:articleDetails.html.twig', {'article': article}) }}
```

Or like this per http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Comment: I will mark it solved tomorrow once StackOverflow will allow me to...  Ok?

Comment: I have struggled with this for months! now I have all those 2 liners to clean up... `{% set var = value %}` followed by `{% include 'some.template.html.twig' %}`

Answer (score 9):

For a template name as a variable, I had to use this format:

```
{% include 'AcmeCalendarBundle:Default:cal_event_' ~ day.item.type ~ '.html.twig' with {'item': day.item} %}
```

Using

```
{{ include 'AcmeCalendarBundle:Default:cal_event_' ~ day.item.type ~ '.html.twig', {'item': day.item} }}
```

did not work.

Comment: first one works great thanks!